# Error when setting statecode to inactive using KingswaySoft/SSIS

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, kingswaysoft

When performing and update statecode to inactive using SSIS and the KingswaySoft adapters I get the below error. Are there any suggestions to resolve this issue?

> CRM service call returned an error: CRM service call returned an error: An unexpected error occurred.(Error Code: -2147220970, Detail Message: An unexpected error occurred.)

Is it possible to capture the web service messages between SSIS/KingswaySoft and CRM using Fiddler? I have tried with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was to upgrade to ver 7.1 of the kingsway soft Adapters.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a CRM 2011? Statecode can be updated on latest versions of CRM only, for 2011 you'll need to use the SetStateRequest message.

Also, if you wanna debug the traces, one option is to log into the CRM front end role server and check the event viewer.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from CRM server side. The only option to troubleshoot the error is to turn on CRM trace log on CRM server side.

For CRM on-prem, you can turn on CRM trace log with the following tool.

- https://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com/

After you have turned on trace log, you can run the data load task, and CRM server will generate some log files under C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Trace folder. The log file is big, and not easy to read. So you would use one of the following tools toread the log files.

- https://pfecrmtracetool.codeplex.com/
- https://crmtracereader.codeplex.com/

If you are using CRM Online, you would want to contact the CRM Online Support team to request for assistance. Alternatively you can create an on-prem environment to reproduce the error message, in which case you can turn on the CRM trace log in the replicate environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the trace logs (eg, because you're using CRM Online), then I would suggest:

1. Turn off any plugins on the entity for the record you're trying to deactivate. It's possible that you have a plugin on update or SetState that's firing and causing the error.
2. Confirm that the statecode and statuscode values you're setting are valid and that the statuscode belongs to the statecode. You can see these values within Customisations.

I've used SSIS and Kingsway soft and it is possible to set a record state without error